# Flowable.compose() to transform to Single or Maybe

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2, reactivex

Is there any operator in RxJava2 which can apply a transformation from `Flowable` to `Single` or `Maybe`? I mean `Flowable.compose()` operator applies a `Transformer` to a `Flowable` and returns another `Flowable`. But I need to apply a transformer which converts a `Flowable` into a `Single` or `Mabye` and which can further be reused multiple times in my application without "[breaking the chain](https://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/)".

Example (in Kotlin):

```kotlin
fun processFirstEven(f: Flowable<Int>): Maybe<Int> {
    return f.filter { i -> i % 2 == 0 }.take(1).singleElement().map { s -> s * 12 }
}

val f: Maybe<Int> = Flowable
        .fromArray(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
        .compose(::processFirstEven) // Does not compile
```

Comment: To transform between the base types, use `to` or `as` instead of `compose`.

Comment: Thank you @akarnokd This looks like what I am looking for. Would you please post this comment as an answer, so I could mark it as accepted?

Comment: I can't. SO will flag it as trivial/link only and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this kind of complex transformation in a single line. It looks this is already quite simple for me:

```
fun takeFirstEven(f: Flowable<Int>): Flowable<Int> {
    return f.filter { i -> i % 2 == 0 }.take(1)
}

val f: Maybe<Int> = Flowable
    .fromArray(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    .compose(::takeFirstEven)
    .singleElement()
```

The good news is that if your goals is just the *reusablility*, you can use [Kotlin's function extension feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) to do exactly that.

Put this code somewhere your code can access:

```
fun <T> Flowable<T>.toMaybe(filter: (T) -> Boolean): Maybe<T> {
    return this.filter(filter).take(1).singleElement()
}
```

Then you can simply use `toMaybe` anywhere with any filter you would like.

```
fun evenFilter(i: Int) = (i % 2) == 0

val f: Maybe<Int> = Flowable
    .fromArray(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    .toMaybe(::evenFilter)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, Kotlin's extension function is not an option in my project as the transformer is supposed to be shared between other JVM languages. The approach with `compose()` followed by `singleElement()` is also not viable, because in the real case (which is more complex, I just provided an oversimplified example) some more logic is then applied to a `Single` before returning it from the transformer. I've adjusted the example to reflect this detail. So maybe I should just submit a feature request to the RX development team.